# Hard-error with simple requires-expression

Tags: c++, c++20

Why does the requires-expression, when evaluating the last static assertion, produce a compile error? When defaulting `T` to `int` (and flipping its condition), everything seems fine. Where in the standard is mention of the difference in expected behavior of such requires-expressions? How to write the last static assertion so that the code works fine without using any SFINAE techniques?

```
#include <concepts>

template<std::integral T>
constexpr auto soft() -> T
{ return T{}; }

template<typename T>
constexpr auto hard() -> std::integral auto
{ return T{}; }

static_assert(not []<typename T = float>
    { return requires { soft<T>(); }; }());

// results in hard error
static_assert(not []<typename T = float>
    { return requires { hard<T>(); }; }());
```

The error message produced by Clang:

```
<source>:8:31: error: deduced type 'float' does not satisfy 'integral'
constexpr auto hard() -> std::integral auto
                         ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
'hard<float>' requested here
    { return requires { hard<T>(); }; }());
                        ^
<source>:16:25: note: in instantiation of requirement here
    { return requires { hard<T>(); }; }());
                        ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:40: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
'(anonymous class)::operator()<float>' requested here
    { return requires { hard<T>(); }; }());
                                       ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/concepts:100:24:
note: because 'is_integral_v<float>' evaluated to false
    concept integral = is_integral_v<_Tp>;
                       ^
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/cGxK38Mej)

---

> If no definition for hard is available (only the declaration with
> constrained auto return type), then there will also be no hard error.
> In that case hard() becomes an invalid expression when substituting
> float, because an expression naming a function template specialization
> with undeduced placeholder return type is not valid.

As mentioned in the comment to user17732522's answer, what should happen if the definition of the function `hard` is provided after evaluting the last static assertion? Should this still result in a hard-error? Clang and GCC seem to disagree about this:

```
#include <concepts>

template<std::integral T>
constexpr auto soft() -> T
{ return T{}; }

template<typename T>
constexpr auto hard() -> std::integral auto;

static_assert(not []<typename T = float>
    { return requires { soft<T>(); }; }());

// fails on Clang -- ok on GCC
static_assert(not []<typename T = float>
    { return requires { hard<T>(); }; }());

template<typename T>
constexpr auto hard() -> std::integral auto
{ return T{}; }
```

The error message produced by Clang:

```
<source>:8:31: error: deduced type 'float' does not satisfy 'integral'
constexpr auto hard() -> std::integral auto;
                         ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
'hard<float>' requested here
    { return requires { hard<T>(); }; }());
                        ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/concepts:100:24:
note: because 'is_integral_v<float>' evaluated to false
    concept integral = is_integral_v<_Tp>;
                       ^
```

[New example](https://godbolt.org/z/1EdoPhjKc)

Comment: It kind of looks like it is behaving as designed. Float isn't an integral

Comment: Your functions `soft` and `hard` do different things: The function `soft` only exists for `T` that satisfy the concept `std::integral` --- SFINAE-style. The template `hard` will be instantiated for any `T`, but it will throw a compile-error if the return type does not satisfy the constraint `std::integral`. You can see this at the different compiler errors generated when trying to invoke either `soft<float>` or `hard<float>`. https://godbolt.org/z/r43rdxbT7

Comment: @joergbrech Please take note of the importance of the requires-expression in which those functions are used: *"The substitution of template arguments into a requires-expression used in a declaration of a templated entity may result in the formation of invalid types or expressions in its requirements, or the violation of semantic constraints of those requirements. In such cases, the requires-expression evaluates to false and does not cause the program to be ill-formed."* As expected, this seems to apply to the first static assertion, but not the second one. The question is why that is.

Comment: @MikelF Then why does the first static assertion works fine but the second one doesn't? If this is behaving as designed, please reference the applicable standardese that explains it.

Comment: @303 Yes I understand that and I don't have an answer to your question (that's why it's just a comment).

Comment: And in the absence of the `hard` instance, the `soft` instance still compiles without failure?

Answer (score 3):

Substituting `float` for `T` results in `soft<T>()` being an invalid expression, because naming the specialization `soft<float>` is not allowed by `soft`'s constraints.

However, the expression `hard<T>()` itself is valid when `float` is substituted for `T`. What isn't valid however is the instantiation of `hard<float>`, which deduces a return type that doesn't satisfy the type constraint on the declared return type.

In other words, in `soft<T>()` the error is in the immediate context of the substitution into the expression, while it isn't for `hard<T>()`.

The instantiation of `hard<float>` is required to deduce the return type in order to verify the validity of the expression. For example if the return type of `hard<float>()` was `A` without type constraint and with

```
struct A { ~A() = delete; };
```

then `hard<float>()` is, as a full-expression including the destructor call, invalid, while it isn't if the return type is e.g. `int` (with or without the `std::integral` constraint).

If no definition for `hard` is available (only the declaration with constrained `auto` return type), then there will also be no hard error. In that case `hard<T>()` becomes an invalid expression when substituting `float`, because an expression naming a function template specialization with undeduced placeholder return type is not valid.

---

There is no way to verify the validity or check the return type of a whole function body. Both are only possible for individual expressions. In your case there is only one expression in the function, so a `requires` clause verifying that the expression (`T{}`) has a type satisfying the concept can be used on `hard`, but since the expression's type is trivial, your `soft` variation would be the simpler solution. A type constraint on the return type can only ever cause hard errors, never SFINAE.

If you don't care about the "verify the validity" part, then you can wrap a function to do the deduction:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto hard_impl()
{ //whatever }

template<typename T>
requires std::integral<decltype(hard_impl<T>())>
constexpr auto hard()
{ return hard_impl<T>(); }
```

Now there is a hard error if substitution of `T` into `//whatever` is ill-formed, but no hard error if it merely results in a return type that doesn't satisfy `std::integral`.

Comment: Since you mentioned the difference of declaring and defining, I have noticed this passage from cppreference: *"If a requires-expression contains invalid types or expressions in its requirements, and it does not appear within the declaration of a templated entity, then the program is ill-formed."* I wonder if that is related to the difference here, or that it simply boils down to *substitution failure outside of the immediate context*.

Comment: *"If no definition for hard is available... then there will also be no hard error. In that case hard<T>() becomes an invalid expression when substituting float..."* But what if the definition is provided at a later point in time? Specifically, after the static assert has been evaluated, should this still result in a hard error? Clang and GCC seem to disagree about this.

Comment: @303 I think the "_and it does not appear within the declaration of a templated entity,_" part is about where the `requires` expression itself is located and just clarifies that e.g. `static_assert(not requires { soft<float>(); });` is a hard error.

Comment: @303 I don't think it is clearly specified at which point in the translation unit the return type is considered deduced in the case of template instantiations (or I don't understand it properly), but without a definition it can't be anywhere in the translation unit.

Comment: *" I think the ... part is about where the requires expression itself is located ..."* Ah yes, that makes a lot of sense now that I read it again.

Comment: Also, when providing the declaration of the `hard` function with a defaulted template argument and without passing `T` to it within the requires-expression, Clang complains about `function with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined` while GCC is still ok with it. That is without providing any definition for `hard` throughout the entire translation unit, so I think it becomes important that your claim about the difference in behavior related to whether to provide a definition for the `hard` function or not, should really be backed by some related passages from the standard.